# Is there a way to highlight specific words inside MS Word text box?

Tags: vba, ms-word

The current VBA code I found highlights specific words in a list that is placed in a regular paragraph. However I need to highlight word placed inside a text box as well. Any ideas on how to highlight text inside text box as well?

```
Sub HighlightWords()
'
' HighlightWords Macro
'
'
Dim Word As range
Dim WordCollection(2) As String
Dim Words As Variant

WordCollection(0) = "Andres"
WordCollection(1) = "just"
WordCollection(2) = "Pending"

Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True

For Each Word In ActiveDocument.Words
For Each Words In WordCollection
With Selection.Find
.Text = Words
.Replacement.Text = ""
.Forward = True
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
.Format = True
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False

End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Next

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Text inside a Text box can be formatted int he same way as text in a normal document.  Now all you need to do is to research how to locate your specific text box.

Comment: A couple of remarks about this code: 1) I don't see the reason for looping the `ActiveDocument.Words` - all this will do is to repeat the other loop and Find for each word in the document, which is totally unnecessary and time consuming. 2) It's a ***very bad*** idea to declare variables that have the same name as keywords in the VBA object model you're using. Word VBA uses both `Word` and `Words` as special things - this can cause real problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this loop:

```
For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count
    ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).Select

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True

    ' do something...
Next i
```